# AWS SES not publishing email content to SNS action

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an SES domain properly configured to deliver mail to an SNS Topic, which in turn, uses an HTTPS endpoint to deliver a mail object to the entered URL, but the "complete raw email" is not being provided by either SES to SNS, or by SNS to the endpoint; only the standard "Received" mail object with "common headers" is being delivered.

Setup - I have an SES ruleset that stipulates handling all mail with a SNSAction that points to an SNS Topic, and that SNS Topic has the HTTPS endpoint specified. SES and SNS are both in the same region, and the SNS HTTP endpoint has been verified.

Upon receiving an email, the SES rule fires and the SNS Topic specified receives an object, and SNS dutifully posts the mail object on to HTTPS endpoint, but without the "content" field, which is what I need (ok, I really only need the "to" address and the email body, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to obtain JUST the body).

If you have thoughts on how to get the raw content and/or just the email body, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: SNS receives the full email object right? If so, can you please add more info on how. you've configured SNS - HTTPS? Screenshots will be particularly helpful in this case if something can't be represented using text

Comment: Ermiya; Unfortunately SNS is NOT receiving the full email object...that is the issue. The SES docs (the seemingly multiple copies of it) indicate that in that one case, the full email would be sent, but that isn't happening; the JSON object I get from SNS via HTTPS call is missing the "content" field. As for SNS - HTTPS config, I have a verified URL endpoint entered, with standard "HTTP retry" attributes. SNS is able to successfully call to HTTPS endpoint; the data that shows up is incomplete.